# Chrome not loading Wingdings font family

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

First let me explain why I want to load Wingdings in chrome. For my company we utilize many custom fonts unfortunately. As part of the configuration, development and setup of the fonts I like to set all my font-family declarations to:

```
font-family: CUSTOM FONT, Wingdings, BACKUP FONTS;
```

This may seem counterproductive but it allows me to know at a glance immediately when a font has failed to load (missing font-file, bad font-face declaration, any other issues).

However I noticed today that it appears as if chrome is ignoring/replacing my system's Wingdings font. It no longer shows weird symbols when the custom font has failed to load.

I don't care if it's Wingdings or not, that's just what I'm used to but is there any really obvious font I can change it to that will immediately make it obvious whenever a font has not loaded? This is for myself and I can't tell the difference between Helvetica, Arial, Times New Roman or any other font unless they are side-by-side.